# ¿Cómo crear bases de datos para cada cliente? No encuentro el error

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo, post

Estoy intentando esto en php

```
    <?php
    class Create_database
{
 protected $pdo;
 protected $name;
 function __construct()
 {
 $this->pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;", "usuario", "contraseña");
 $this->name=$_POST['name'];
 }
 //creamos la base de datos y las tablas que necesitemos
 public function my_db()
 {
        //creamos la base de datos si no existe
 $crear_db = $this->pdo->prepare('CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS ' . $this->name . ' COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci');
 $crear_db->execute();

 //decimos que queremos usar la tabla que acabamos de crear
 if($crear_db):
 $use_db = $this->pdo->prepare('USE $this->name');   
 $use_db->execute();
 endif;

 //si se ha creado la base de datos y estamos en uso de ella creamos las tablas
 if($use_db):
 //creamos la tabla usuarios
 $crear_tb_users = $this->pdo->prepare('
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Info (
 id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 nombre varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
 apellido varchar(150) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
 direccion varchar(150) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
 pais varchar(150) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
 ip varchar(150) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
 telefono varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
 contrasena varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
 registro date NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (id)
     )'); 
 $crear_tb_users->execute();

 //creamos la tabla posts
 $crear_tb_posts = $this->pdo->prepare('
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Compras (
 factura int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 referencia int(11) NOT NULL,
 email varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
 nombre varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
 valor varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
 ip varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
 productos text COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
 metodo de pago text COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
 fecha datetime NOT NULL,
 dirección datetime NOT NULL,
 telefono datetime NOT NULL,

 PRIMARY KEY (id)
 )'); 
 $crear_tb_posts->execute();
 endif;

 }
}
//ejecutamos la función my_db para crear nuestra bd y las tablas
$db = new Create_database();
$db->my_db();
if($db->my_db()){
echo "se creo la base de datos";
}
else{
echo "no se creo la base de datos";
}
?>
```

necesito crear bases de datos para cada cliente pero no logro crear la base de datos pero no encuentro el error

Comment: estas creando mal la clase, el valor  inicial es vacio por obvias razones primero se crea la clase y realiza el post, debes crear un constructor y pasar el valor, asi te funcionara!

Comment: El `$_POST['name'];` debes recuperarlo donde creas la instancia de la Clase, no dentro de la Clase misma. La Clase en sí no está nunca expuesta directamente en el código, sino que es como una entidad de la cual creas instancias (mediante `new` en este caso). Entonces es a esa instancia de la clase a la que le pasas el valor del POST, sea en el constructor, sea en otro método.

Comment: Por ejemplo si quieres pasar los valores al constructor, lo modificas así: `function __construct($name) {  $this->name=$name;  //Resto del código}` Y el valor del POST lo recuperas **fuera de la clase, no dentro**:  `$name=$_POST['name']; //Creas una instancia de la clase y le pasas el valor recuperado por POST db = new Create_database($name);`

Comment: bien gracias por su ayuda con el $_POST['name'] ahora tengo problemas es porque no se genera la base de datos

Comment: Eso puede deberse a otras cosas, por ejemplo, que la conexión no se está realizando, que el usuario no tiene permisos para crear bases de datos, que hay errores de sintaxis en la consulta de creación, etc, etc, etc.

Comment: A parte de lo mencionado mucho cuidado con las concatenaciones de datos externos, te expones a una inyeción SQL grave, mas aun cuando se disponen de permisos de estructura y/o administracion. Ademas que en este caso PDO::prepare no te puede salvar en todas las sentencias, por lo que te recomendaria crear un metodo para garantizar esto.

Comment: bien gracias por los consejos ahora revisé la conexión funciona correctamente el usuario tiene todos los permisos ahora lo que falta es que me ayuden a encontrar los errores en la sintaxis

Comment: ¿Qué errores recibes? ¿En qué líneas? Recuerda que las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta. Tenemos el comportamiento esperado (crear la base de datos), tenemos el código (compartido en la pregunta), deberías añadir los errores que estés recibiendo.